# Translating new C++ to old C++

Tags: software-development, c++

C++11 and C++14 introduce a lot of new features that make programmers' lives easier. However, in various environments (e.g. CUDA), support for the most modern C++ features may be weak or nonexistent.

Many of these features (e.g. `auto`, `decltype`, `constexpr`, variadic templates) do not add any challenges to code generation, and really only require a parser that understands the constructs. In principle, unless honestly new functionality (e.g. `thread_local`) is used, there could be a tool that takes C++14 code and converts it into something that could be built with something that only understands the C++03 language.

Does such a tool exist? (or are my presumptions way off base?)

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/convert-to-c.html.  In particular Comeau Computing used to have a reputation for this, but they seem to have stumbled and now look like they are picking up pieces, See http://www.comeaucomputing.com/.  I have no experience with them previously or present, so this is not a recommendation, just a pointer.